# How to take value for Object result in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to print specific value from object result. here is i am execute SQL query and take all data from View tables, All data coming from "Employee_Information" view(table). 
**hr_controller.rb**

```
class HrController < ApplicationController

  def internal_employee_page        
    @employees = MysqlConnection.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM Employee_Information")
  end 
end
```

**internal_employee_page.html.erb** this is my first view

```
<div id="job_details">
    <% @employees.each do |emp| %>
        <%= render partial: "hr/employee_details", locals: {emp: emp} %>
    <% end %>               
</div>
```

**_employee_details.html.erb** this is my second view

```
<h3> User Name : <%= emp%> </h3>
```

like this I am trying to print all value
**then I got following result**
[image]
I want to print each value
**I tried this also** in my second view

```
<h3> User Name : <%= emp.full_name%> </h3>
```

But I got Error:
[image]
Please help me I tried every thing according to my knowledge, where am I wrong and what is problems

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `ActiveRecord` or any other ORM databse mapper? It seems like you would like to and given your stack wiring this up is very simple in rails. AS of right now all your "Objects" are actually just `Hash`es so all operations on them should be performed in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h3> User Name : <%= emp["full_name"] %> </h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to read values from Hash,so `emp.full_name` will not work, you can read value from hash like `Hash['key']`

so for full_name do `<%= emp['full_name'] %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3> User Name : <%= emp.full_name%> </h3>
```

full_name is not an attribute of employee instance that's why you got this error. try fetch specific attribute which is present in that employee instance.

Comment: `full_name` is present but employee is not an instance of `Employee` but rather an instance of `Hash`

Answer (score 0):

Right now your response objects are just simple `Hash` objects and to access the values for keys you would need to use `Hash` methods such as `[]` or `fetch` to retrieve the values. If you would like more method like syntax you could do one of the following:

- Use ActiveRecord or another ORM mapper
- Create Dynamic or Static classes yourself and map the results to them
- Monkey Patch Hash with something like `method_missing` to fake this concept

Comment: I'd add another option, which is using OpenStruct to achieve similar results. `OpenStruct.new(emp)` would allow him to retrieve that attribute with dot notation.

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim fair. I ignored OpenStruct due to memory leaks in 1.8 and early 1.9.3 (probably fixed by now but it put a bad taste in my mouth). Also it has proven to be a slow performer on larger data sets.